# Sending data recursively using jquery $.ajax gives stack overflow error

Tags: jquery, recursion

Why am I getting "too much recursion" error when I do the following?

```
    function sendTheNames() {

       alert("start submitting names..");

        return function (array) {

            var name = $(array.shift()).text();

            $.ajax({
                url: "test.jsp?name=" + name,
                complete: function () {
                    if (array.length > 0) {
                        return arguments.callee(array);
                    }
                }
            });
        };

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var selectedNames = [];
        $('ul li input:checked').each(function () {
            selectedNames.push($(this).parent());
        });

        alert("begin");

        sendTheNames()(selectedNames);

        alert("done");
    });
```

Comment: Interesting question, but that's a really weird way to code it. Wouldn't a normal loop work better? Better yet, a POST request?

Comment: @deceze, the above is just a simplified code. And the business logic requires me to submit the data asynchronously one by one to the server like this (one data per request). I must not submit it as a bunch of array in a POST request as you suggested, and I must wait for the submission to complete before submitting another. Do you have cleaner way of doing this without recursion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you absolutely need *asynchronous*, separate calls, at least do a little simpler recursion along the lines of this:

```
var selectedNames = ['Abe', 'Burt', 'Chris'];

function sendNames() {
    var name = selectedNames.shift();

    $.ajax({
        url: "test.jsp?name=" + name,
        complete: function () {
            if (selectedNames.length > 0) {
                sendNames();
            }
        }
    });
}

sendNames();
```

Answer (score 2):

because `arguments.callee` in that context refers to `complete: function () {...}`

You are recursing without getting any closer to a terminal condition. Essentially

```
function complete() {
    if (array.length > 0) {
        return complete(array);
    }
}
```

to have it recur to some other function put this inside the function you want to recur to:

```
var outerCallee = arguments.callee;
```

and recur using

```
return outerCallee(array);
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question spot on, very educational. Now I understand javascript a little better, this will surely come in handy down the road. I tested your solution and it works, but I accept deceze answer because it is more readable.